# Colorbox IFrame opens a URL in the browser instead of a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I used Colorbox in my aspx project and I used the Iframe from example 1. I copied the css and js files mentioned in the html page but when clicking on the link, it opens up the page in the browser itself whereas I want it to show up in the box like in the examples.

Here's the code -

```
<a class='iframe' href="#" onclick="$.colorbox({href:'http://wikipedia.com', iframe:true, width:'90%', height:'90%'});">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the colorbox in an element on the page:

```
<a class='iframe' href="#" onclick="$('#container').colorbox({href:'http://wikipedia.com', iframe:true, width:'90%', height:'90%'});">Click here</a>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Didn't worked. When I use this code, it doesn't opens anything. :/

Answer (score 0):

You must instead do this -

```
<a href="your_link" target="frame1"> Click me </a>

<iframe id="frame1" src="your_default_src"></iframe>
```